# MySQL VALUES() function not working with Codeigniter db->query()

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to make this work:

```
$articles_id = 105; // comes from argument
$type = 'units_out'; // comes from argument
$quantity = 4; // comes from argument
$date = date('Y-m-d');

$sql = "INSERT INTO stock (articles_id, date, units_in, units_out)
                    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
                    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE $type = IF(VALUES($type) - $quantity >= 0, VALUES($type) - $quantity, 0)";

$res = $this->db->query($sql, array($articles_id, $date, 0, $quantity));
```

The record already exists, so it does an update. The initial value of *units_out* in BD is **2**, and its an ***UNSIGNED MEDIUMINT***  field. So, since it's unsigned type, 2 - 4 = -2, which for an UNSIGNED MEDIUMINT means start counting down from its max value.

After the query, *units_out=16777215*. I want to avoid this behaviour by using the **VALUES()** function of MySQL, but it isn't working if I use it with bd->query()

I've tried by directly doing it in PHPMyAdmin and it does work, *units_out* results in **0**. Why this isn't working in Codeigniter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add one more condition in your if,   (VALUES($type) > $quantity) , like

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO stock (articles_id, date, units_in, units_out)
                    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
                    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE $type = IF((VALUES($type) > $quantity) and (VALUES($type) - $quantity >= 0), VALUES($type) - $quantity, 0)";
```

or simply add the greater than condition other than checking for subtraction > 0

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO stock (articles_id, date, units_in, units_out)
                    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
                    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE $type = IF(VALUES($type) >= $quantity, VALUES($type) - $quantity, 0)";
```

Comment: It works, thank you! How come my query worked if I directly used it in PhpMyAdmin, but not in Codeigniter?